# Rails: How can this be done with a has_one association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, model-associations, has-one

My model has two columns, one named `foo_id` and the other `bar_id`.

I'm wondering if it's possible to turn these two simple methods into has_one associations:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def foobar_foo
    Foobar.find( self.foo_id )
  end

  def foobar_bar
    Foobar.find( self.bar_id )
  end
end
```

Perhaps I've been staring at the documentation for too long, but I can't seem to find a way to tell Rails to use `self.foo_id` as the foreign key for the other model.

I'm aware that in most cases this should instead be a `has_many :through` or maybe a `belongs_to`, but for the sake of argument I'm interested to learn if this is possible with a `has_one`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally had a chance to revisit this problem and incidentally, stumbled across a solution within the first few minutes of trying..

```
  has_one :bar, primary_key: :bar_id, foreign_key: :id, class_name: 'Foobar'
  has_one :foo, primary_key: :foo_id, foreign_key: :id, class_name: 'Foobar'
```

Works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
has_one :foo, class_name: "Foobar", foreign_key: :foo_id
has_one :bar, class_name: "Foobar", foreign_key: :bar_id
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one